# SQL Server 2016 database Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-backups, in-memory-database, database-restore

Is there any different approach to restore a SQL Database backup having memory optimized tables as we know that there's additional filegroup present for holding In-Memory data.

Comment: There's no difference I can think of... Are you doing anything special with your backup / restore commands, or have you hit any issues which prompted this question?  You may want to ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as those guys know these processes in more depth...

Comment: @JohnLBevan nothing special just backup and restore database. There's XTP related error coming while performing restore operation. I think it's related to memory-optimized filegroup.

Comment: Right, so you're experiencing a *specific* problem and rather than giving people the *details* relating to your problem you're *guessing* at a root cause and then asking for *general* information about the feature you've decided to blame. A much better question would focus on your *issue*, including specific error messages, and then feel free to *suggest* that you believe it's related to X.

Comment: Not sure... As Damien mentions, please could you share the commands you're running to perform the backup & restore, and the related exception you're seeing when you get the error so we can delve into that issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I switched to dba.stackexchange after John's reply. However the restore command showing error for not able to create xtp folder for memory optimized database while performing restore operation.

Comment: questions seems to be good(capturing different problem/scenario). Can you please provide a sample example/little more detail of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.             -Thanks,

Comment: @ShiwanginiShishulkar thanks for showing interest into this issue, however I have solved this problem. You may check the [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227641/database-restoration-issue-msg-3156-level-16-state-6) for more detail.